# Failed to resolve tapandpay dependency in local

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-tap-and-pay

Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-tapandpay:17.1.2
Instruction from developers.google:

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tapandpay:17.1.0'
  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have added the unzipped SDK
  // location to your root build.gradle file as a local maven dependency
}
allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        google() // Google's public Maven repository
        maven { url "file:/path/to/your/repo/m2repository/" }  // Local path to the folder into which you unzipped the SDK
    }
}
```

```
ERROR:
Execution failed for task
> Could not resolve all files for configuration 
   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-tapandpay:17.1.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
```

#### I can't find right way

Comment: Post the error too for better understanding

Comment: can you post link to "developers.google" site with mentioned instruction? there is no such artifact (`play-services-tapandpay`) in [official Google's maven repo](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.google.android.gms)...

Comment: play-services-tapandpay - this lib has private access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my bug.
I added to build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
       maven { url "file:/*pathto*/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this error by following :

1. Extract the lib folder
2. Move the folder to this path (*your
   android sdk path* Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository)
3. Add the previous path to build.gradle file

> ```
> allprojects {
>     repositories {
>         google()
>         jcenter()
>          maven { url "file:*your path here*/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository"}
> ```

4. Make sure the the lib version is matching the dependency version  that we've added.