# How to access play-services-tapandpay repository in production app?

Tags: android, android-studio, maven, android-pay, google-pay

In my application I am working on play-services-tapandpay.
[With the help of following link, adding dependency in local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68982591/failed-to-resolve-tapandpay-dependency-in-local) I am able to run the code smoothly in local.

Now the problem is I am creating production apk to deploy in play store, where I am not getting idea how to access "play-services-tapandpay" dependency which was placed in local.

I did not find any artifactory repository to access it from server.

Can anyone let me know how to access that local dependency file from server.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options to try:

##### Option 1 - Server with admin access

If you have admin access to the server you could copy the `play-services-tapandpay` folder to the server and refer to it in you gradle file (just like you did locally):

```
maven { url "file:*your server absolute path here*"}
```

##### Option 2 - AAR in the libs folder

You could put the `play-services-tapandpay-x.y.z.aar` file in your project `libs` folder and ensure you have the following in your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
    ...
}
```

You should also manually add all the dependencies from `play-services-tapandpay-x.y.z.pom` to your `build.gradle`.

##### Option 3 - Upload the files to a private Nexus Maven repository

The files you are required to upload are: `maven-metadata.xml`, `aar` and `pom`.

You could use the UI or if you prefer the command line, these should be the commands:

```
curl -v -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD \
--upload-file com/google/android/gms/play-services-tapandpay/maven-metadata.xml \
http://your.private.repository/repository/maven2-release-hosted/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tapandpay/maven-metadata.xml

curl -v -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD \
--upload-file com/google/android/gms/play-services-tapandpay/x.y.z/play-services-tapandpay-x.y.z.pom \
http://your.private.repository/repository/maven2-release-hosted/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tapandpay/x.y.z/play-services-tapandpay-x.y.z.pom

curl -v -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD \
--upload-file com/google/android/gms/play-services-tapandpay/x.y.z/play-services-tapandpay-x.y.z.aar \
http://your.private.repository/repository/maven2-release-hosted/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tapandpay/x.y.z/play-services-tapandpay-x.y.z.aar
```

Reference: https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115006744008

Then in your `settings.gradle` you need to add your private Maven repository:

```
maven {
    url("http://your.private.repository/repository/maven2-group")
    allowInsecureProtocol(true)
    credentials {
        username("$System.env.USERNAME")
        password("$System.env.PASSWORD")
    }
}
```

Finally, you can use the dependency in you `build.gradle`:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tapandpay:x.y.z"
```